# $http.delete server request from not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do a http delete request to my API but the call is failing. The Get and Post methods work perfectly, but not the delete call. My guess is that the problem is on the client code but can't figure out what. This is the client's code

```
        $http.delete("http://localhost:69174/api/posts", postId)
            .then(function (response) {

                // sucess delete
                viewModel.posts.delete(response.data);
                viewModel.newPost = {};

            }, function () {

                // failed to delete
                viewModel.errorMessage = "Failed to delete post";

            })
            .finally(function () {

            });
```

and this is the API function

```
    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task Delete(Guid id)
    {
        await _postsRepo.DeletePostAsync(id);
    }
```

Also one more question, what is the best practice this make http calls to the API from the client, making requests directly from my AngularJs controller or the ASP.NET controller?

Comment: Did you confirm the destination URL in the developer tools?

Comment: Yes I did. I was able to getting working and posted how I did, but I am wondering why it wasn't working with my previous implementation, and if there is a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allowed the call to be sucessful, but not sure if it is a good practice to pass an id over the url even when deleting

```
$http.delete("http://localhost:69174/api/posts/" + postId)
        .then(function (response) {
            ...
        }, function () {
            ...
        })
        .finally(function () {
            ...
        });
```

Comment: "not sure if it is a good practice to pass an id over the url even when deleting", it's fine, and a standard of RESTful design. If the rest of your API adheres to the basics of REST design, consider using `$resource` instead of `$http` to get a simpler abstraction.

Comment: Yes, the rest of my API follows RESTful  design. How would I do that? I tried just replacing $http with $resource on my code and it doesn't make the call to the API

Comment: oh and thanks for your feedback on the good practices question :)

Comment: Consuming `$resource` works a bit differently than `$http`. There's lots of guides and documentation on the subject. [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) being one starting point.